# Qt Multiple file filters, force one extension

Tags: c++, qt

in a Qt dialog for saving a file, I have multiple options for file filters.

For instance, my filter is `"Text Files (*.txt, *.pdf);;TXT Files (*.txt);;PDF files(*.pdf)"`.

This is my code:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
dialog.setNameFilter(filter.c_str());
dialog.setAcceptMode( QFileDialog::AcceptSave );
dialog.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_TITLE_EXPORT_CLOUD);
if (!dialog.exec())
    return;

QString fileName;
auto    fileName = dialog.selectedFiles().at(0);
```

Now, the user may not introduce a file extension, so it should be the dialog's responsibility to force one based on the selected file filter.

For the case of multiple extensions, I could use `QDialog::setDefaultSuffix()`, but this would not suffice because if I set the default suffix to, for instance, .pdf, the user may select the `TXT files (*.txt)` filter, and I would override the user decision.

How can I force the file extension based on the selected filter?

Thank you

---

There is also the `QFileDialod::selectedNameFilter()`, but basing my code on this would force me to check for the existence of the file afterwards, for not overriding ([Is there a way to automatically add extensions to a file using QFileDialog on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822177/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-add-extensions-to-a-file-using-qfiledialog-on-li))

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it afterwards.

You can get the `selectedNameFilter`.
Then you should check if the selected filename has the same extension as the `selectedNameFilter`.

If they are not the same, you can choose to add it, or change the extension.

Comment: The problem with this is if the file exists with the changed extension, I would have to call the default "overwrite" dialog.

Comment: This is a great reason not to automatically add file extensions to stuff.